# Quickblox: Is there a way to retrieve dialogs of all users?

Tags: quickblox

Currently, Quickblox's REST API allows the retrieval of all dialogs for a single logged user.

As an admin, I need the ability to retrieve dialogs for all users within the past 24hrs that have unread messages. 
After that I need to send an email to the users who haven't responded to those unread messages.
Is there an easy approach to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it would be very convenient, I agree. Unfortunately, at the moment one can retrieve all dialogs only for the currently logged in user.